# Мне ваше предложение неинтересно / не интересно

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Мне ваше предложение неинтересно / не интересно.

> Мне неинтересно / не интересно, что здеся происходит.

> Мне неважно / не важно, кот ли это или кошка.